# Shapeless: Implicitly in the function body

Tags: scala, shapeless

I have following code snippet:

```
val reprEncoder: CsvEncoder[String :: Int :: Boolean :: HNil] =
  implicitly
```

What does `implicitly` mean here?

Comment: Please have alook at documentation before asking

Comment: I looked it, but could not configure it out. That because I was asking here.

Comment: `implicitly` is defined here: https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.12.x/src/library/scala/Predef.scala#L187

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means: "summon the implicit instance that you have in scope for the type `CsvEncoder[String :: Int :: Boolean :: HNil]`". The following simple example, in a Scala REPL session, should make it clear:

```
$ scala
Welcome to Scala 2.12.3 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_144).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala> implicit val str: String = "hello"
str: String = hello

scala> val anotherStr: String = implicitly
anotherStr: String = hello
```

As you can see the value assigned to `anotherStr` is that of `str` which is the only implicit value of type `String` in scope. Note that if you have more than one implicit value of the same type in scope compilation will fail with the error: "ambiguous implicit values". Indeed:

```
scala> implicit val str: String = "hello"
str: String = hello

scala> implicit val str2: String = "world"
str2: String = world

scala> val anotherStr: String = implicitly
<console>:16: error: ambiguous implicit values:
 both value StringCanBuildFrom in object Predef of type => 
scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[String,Char,String]
 and method $conforms in object Predef of type [A]=> A <:< A
 match expected type T
       val anotherStr: String = implicitly
                                ^

scala>
```